# App and library in qbs: one project multiple products or vice-versa

Tags: qt, qbs

A question about best practices when using Qt and Qbs:  I have a static library and an app that uses it.  It looks like I can have a single qbs project with two products or two projects with one product each.  Which is better?  [And why?]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just pulled down the qbs source which contains nice examples.  qbs itself is built, unsurprisingly, by qbs so that serves as a good example, too.

It seems that a single project with multiple products, often referenced from other qbs files is the intended usage.  Not sure why that way is better.

Comment: Yes, this is the intended usage. Multiple Projects are generally used when you are referencing an external project that isn't part of your own software (for example, a library dependency). In this case you might use a SubProject item (http://doc.qt.io/qbs/subproject-item.html) to reference the external Project.

Comment: Thanks for the external project use case!  That should come in handy.. today. :)